# Save button center position and load it in view controller Loaded

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, core-graphics, uipangesturerecognizer

Hi guys sorry for my English, I´m working on an app that is capable of moving a bunch of buttons, each of them, on-screen with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, saving the center position (x,y) and tag in `Core Data`.

When the app starts from zero and I load position from `Core Data`:

```
if let c = ButtonEntity.getButton(tag: self.tag)
    {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5)
    {
            self.center = CGPoint(x: CGFloat( c.xPoint ?? 0), y: CGFloat( c.yPoint ?? 0))
    }
```

This is from a custom `UIButton` Class and the buttons are placed by default in a certain position with `auto layout`

The problem is that in some cases some buttons return to their `auto layout` positions instead of `coreData` center position assigned on `viewDidLoad`

is there any solution or another way to do this?
thanks

Comment: *"... buttons return to their auto layout positions ..."* -- correct. You cannot mix auto-layout constraints and frame changes (setting `.center` is a frame change). Either use **only frames** or **only constraints**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help understand why we cannot mix constraints with `.center` (frame) changes...

Here are two almost identical view controllers.

Each adds a button, and sets the button's `.centerXAnchor` and `.centerYAnchor` to the view's `.centerXAnchor` and `.centerYAnchor`.

We add a pan gesture to the button so we can drag it around.

We also implement `touchesBegan(...)` where all we do is change the button title. Doing so will trigger an auto-layout pass.

In the pan func in the first example, we use a typical "get the pan location and update the `.center` property:

```
@objc func pan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let v = sender.view, let sv = v.superview else { return }
    if sender.state == .changed {
        let pt: CGPoint = sender.location(in: sv)
        // update the button's .center property (changes the frame)
        v.center = pt
    }
}
```

This works fine, until we tap anywhere off the button. At that point, we change the button title and auto-layout moves the button back to its center X and Y constraints.

In the second example, we add X and Y constraints as var / properties to the controller:

```
// btn center constraints
//  we will modify the .constants when panning
var xConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var yConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

set them up in `viewDidLoad()`, and then *move the button* in the pan gesture like this:

```
@objc func pan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let v = sender.view, let sv = v.superview else { return }
    if sender.state == .changed {
        let pt: CGPoint = sender.location(in: sv)
        let xOff = pt.x - sv.center.x
        let yOff = pt.y - sv.center.y
        // update the .constant values for the btn center x/y
        xConstraint.constant = xOff
        yConstraint.constant = yOff
    }
}
```

Now, tapping anywhere else will change the button title, but it will stay where it is because we've changed the `.constant` values of our X and Y constraints.

**Set `.center` -- problems**

```
class DemoVC: UIViewController {
    
    let btnToMove = UIButton()
    
    var tapCounter: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        btnToMove.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(btnToMove)
        
        btnToMove.setTitle("Test", for: [])
        btnToMove.backgroundColor = .red
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btnToMove.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            btnToMove.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan(_:)))
        btnToMove.addGestureRecognizer(p)
    }
    
    @objc func pan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let v = sender.view, let sv = v.superview else { return }
        if sender.state == .changed {
            let pt: CGPoint = sender.location(in: sv)
            // update the button's .center property (changes the frame)
            v.center = pt
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // update the button title - which will trigger an auto-layout pass
        tapCounter += 1
        btnToMove.setTitle("Test \(tapCounter)", for: [])
    }
    
}
```

**Update constraint `.constant` values -- no problems**

```
class DemoVC: UIViewController {
    
    let btnToMove = UIButton()
    
    var tapCounter: Int = 0
    
    // btn center constraints
    //  we will modify the .constants when panning
    var xConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var yConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btnToMove.setTitle("Test", for: [])
        btnToMove.backgroundColor = .red

        btnToMove.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(btnToMove)

        xConstraint = btnToMove.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        yConstraint = btnToMove.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            xConstraint, yConstraint,
        ])
        
        let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan(_:)))
        btnToMove.addGestureRecognizer(p)
    }
    
    @objc func pan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let v = sender.view, let sv = v.superview else { return }
        if sender.state == .changed {
            let pt: CGPoint = sender.location(in: sv)
            let xOff = pt.x - sv.center.x
            let yOff = pt.y - sv.center.y
            // update the .constant values for the btn center x/y
            xConstraint.constant = xOff
            yConstraint.constant = yOff
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // update the button title - which will trigger an auto-layout pass
        tapCounter += 1
        btnToMove.setTitle("Test \(tapCounter)", for: [])
    }

}
```

Comment: ohh it's better than may approach but coding your solution resize my buttons when I drag the button as well as change its positions, I write the code un my custom uiButton class

Comment: @Omar9700 - this was just example code to show you why mixing frames and constraints doesn't work. If you are trying the above code (using center X/Y constraints) and your button is "resizing" while dragging, it sounds like you are initially setting the **Top** and **Leading** constraints. If that's the case, then modify the `.constant` for *those* constraints... don't add new center constraints.